# How do I configure the parameters that ALE sends to prettier for ruby?

Tags: neovim, plugin-ale, filetype-ruby

Note: this is a neovim question, not stock vim

I have both `rbprettier` and `prettier` with the ruby plugin installed on my system. If I pipe a Ruby file into `rbprettier`, or if I pipe it into `prettier --parser ruby`, I get back a properly formatted version of the file.

I have ALE configured to format on save, and when ALE pipes the file into `prettier`, it always does so with `--parser babel`, which triggers fatal errors.

This is my ALE fixer configuration:

```
let g:ale_fixers = {
\   '*': ['remove_trailing_lines', 'trim_whitespace'],
\   'javascript': ['prettier', 'eslint'],
\   'typescript': ['prettier', 'eslint'],
\   'ruby': ['prettier'],
\   'rust': ['rustfmt'],
\}
let g:ale_fix_on_save = 1
```

How can I reconfigure ALE to either call `rbprettier` directly for Ruby files, or to add the `--parser ruby` option instead of `--parser javascript` when I'm working in a Ruby file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALE doesn't seem to support `prettier` for Ruby in its default configuration.

Though it offers enough hooks for you to use a different executable (such as `rbprettier`) or to pass it additional arguments (such as `--parser ruby`).

You can override these with buffer-local variables `b:ale_javascript_prettier_executable` and `b:ale_javascript_prettier_options`. See [`autoload/ale/fixers/prettier.vim` in the ALE source tree](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/blob/master/autoload/ale/fixers/prettier.vim) for the code that defines and uses these variables.

You can try something like the following:

```
augroup ale_ruby
  au!
  au FileType ruby let b:ale_javascript_prettier_executable = 'rbprettier'
  " Or:
  au FileType ruby let b:ale_javascript_prettier_options = '--parser ruby'
augroup END
```

Note you only need one or the other, not both!

Another alternative is to consider one of the fixers for Ruby supported out-of-the-box. You can find the registry in [`autoload/ale/fix/registry.vim` in the source tree](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/blob/master/autoload/ale/fix/registry.vim), if you search for "ruby" you will find it supports `rubocop`, `rufo`, `sorbet` and `standardrb`.

And one final approach is that you can write your own custom Vim function for a fixer, in which you could invoke `prettier` however you like. See [`:help ale-fix`](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/blob/v2.5.0/doc/ale.txt#L212) for some more details on that.

Comment: Did not try the first form, but did try the second form with great success!